# Allowing GRUB to access network in BIOS mode

Tags: networking, grub2, dhcp, bios

I want grub to fetch some configuration via tftp/http.

Using efi I can do `insmod efinet` and `net_ls_cards` will list my network cards which I can configure and use.

Using PXE in BIOS/legacy mode `net_ls_cards` will also show my network card and allows me to use it.

However using BIOS/legacy mode and running the grub binary from local disk `net_ls_cards` does not show any cards and I do not see an obvious module to load.

Any ideas how to teach GRUB the presence of my network cards in this case?

Comment: I do not believe that is possible in BIOS legacy mode.

Comment: At least pxe booting works perfectly fine in BIOS legacy mode. If a grub binary retrieved from a remote server is able to access network I see no reason why a grub binary retrieved from the local disk shouldn't be able to do so.

Comment: UEFI-based systems support a standardized structured network stack.  BIOS network stacks if even present are vendor specific.